# Select rows where some values are not in other table

Tags: sql, oracle

A and B of table T3 are the same as A and B from T1.
Basically what I need to do is select all the values that aren't on T3.
If there is a line with A,B on T3 I don't wanna show it.

```
SELECT T1.A, T1.B, T1.C
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.X=T2.X
AND NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT T3.A, T3.B
   FROM T3
)
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: FYI: The convention in an `EXISTS` subquery is to select some a fixed scalar value like `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE ...` because it doesn't matter what records the subquery returns, just whether or not it returns records at all. It's my understanding that the columns SELECTed in the exists subquery won't actually be evaluated anyway, so it doesn't really matter what you use from a performance standpoint. But the convention is generally to use `SELECT 1`.

Comment: I don't know that there's a particular convention for that -- I always select NULL to express a lack of interest in whatever is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.A, T1.B, T1.C
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.X=T2.X
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM T3
   WHERE T3.A = T1.A AND T3.B = T1.B
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select T1.A,T1.B,T1.C
from T1
inner join T2
on T1.X=T2.X
left join T3 on T1.A=T3.A and T1.B=T3.B
where T3.A is null
```

Comment: I don't think that Oracle is going to do the efficient anti-join with this method that it would do for the NOT EXISTS method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that using subqueries like

```
SELECT T1.A, T1.B, T1.C
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.X=T2.X
AND T1.A NOT IN (SELECT T3.A FROM T3)
AND T2.B Not IN (SELECT T3.B FROM T3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.A, T1.B, T1.C
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.X=T2.X
AND (T1.A, T1.B) NOT IN (SELECT T3.A, T3.B   FROM T3 )
```